# Carrierwave public URL using amazon S3 gives "Access Denied"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am trying to host an API using Carrierwave/Fog to host the image.  I configured

```
config.fog_public = true
```

However whenever I access the URL of the image, AWS returns an "Access Denied" error.  Is it currently possible to use Fog with AWS to serve public URLs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out I had to recreate the versions with the new configuration settings.

Comment: What about accepting your own answer, so others might benefit of it?

Comment: hahah will do, but stack overflow says i need to wait 22 hours before i can accept my own answer.

Comment: what is exactky recreating the versions with the new configuration settings